# Get string between two strings

Tags: python, regex

```
<p>I'd like to find the string between the two paragraph tags.</p><br><p>And also this string</p>
```

How would I get the string between the first two paragraph tags? And then, how would I get the string between the 2nd paragraph tags?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r'<p>.+?</p>',string)
```

The following is your text run in console.

```
>>>import re
>>>string = """<p>I'd like to find the string between the two paragraph tags.</p><br><p>And also this string</p>"""
>>>re.findall('<p>.+?</p>',string)
["<p>I'd like to find the string between the two paragraph tags.</p>", '<p>And also this string</p>']
```

Comment: I've given you an upvote, but please correct these misspells in frirst fragment. Should be `</p>`

Comment: This might sound stupid but how come this doesn't work?     `split = re.findall('<p>.+?</p>',content)` ......
    `second = split[1]`......it gives me an `index out of range` error. How do I get the 2nd element?

Comment: @Zorgan, could you have changed the content?
it works in my console:

`>>> split = re.findall('<p>(.+?)</p>',string)
>>> split[1]
'And also this string'`

Comment: Yeah it was my content, i've fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

If you want the string between the p tags (**excluding the p tags**) then add parenthesis to **.+?** in the findall method

```
import re
    string = """<p>I'd like to find the string between the two paragraph tags.</p><br><p>And also this string</p>"""
    subStr = re.findall(r'<p>(.+?)</p>',string)
    print subStr
```

> Result

```
["I'd like to find the string between the two paragraph tags.", 'And also this string']
```

Comment: Superb. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

In between `<p>` and `</p>`

```
In [7]: content = "<p>I'd like to find the string between the two paragraph tags.</p><br><p>And also this string</p>"

In [8]: re.findall(r'<p>(.+?)</p>', content)
Out[8]: 
["I'd like to find the string between the two paragraph tags.",
 'And also this string']
```