# Find string between two characters inside of dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary, python-re

You can I find a substring between characters I want to find this character `svm`?
I looked at [Get string between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258529/get-string-between-two-strings/44258570) and [Find string between two substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368969/find-string-between-two-substrings). So this is my string `('svm', SVC())` And I want to find all between `' '` so the result should be `svm` or `dct_test`

```py
import re 
dict_SupportVectorMachine = {
    "classifier": ('svm', SVC()),
    "parameters": {'svm__C':[0.001,0.01,0.1,10, 100],
                   'svm__gamma':[0.1,0.01],
                   'svm__kernel':['linear', 'sigmoid']}
}

string = dict_SupportVectorMachine['classifier']
string2 = ('dct_test', ThisCouldbeLongerAndShorter())
subStr = re.findall(r"('(.+?)',",string)
print(subStr)
```

```py
[OUT]
error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0
```

Comment: `)` is a special character in regex, you seemed to have an unclosed parenthesis or a parenthesis that isn't meant to be here.

Comment: See my edited answer, you don't have at all to handle string manipulations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a `tuple` of 2 elements : a `str` and a `SVC` instance, just get the first index

```
dict_SupportVectorMachine = {
    "classifier": ('svm', SVC()),
    "parameters": {}
}

classif = dict_SupportVectorMachine['classifier']
print(classif[0])  # svm
```

---

#### OLD answer due to different question

The parenthesis is a special char for building groups, for a real parenthesis yo need to escape it `\(`. Also use `search` and not `findall` here

```
import re

string = "('svm', SVC())"
print(re.findall(r"\('(.+?)',", string))  # ['svm']
print(re.search(r"\('(.+?)',", string).group(1))  # svm

string2 = "('dct_test', ThisCouldbeLongerAndShorter()))"
print(re.findall(r"\('(.+?)',", string2))  # ['dct_test']
print(re.search(r"\('(.+?)',", string2).group(1))  # dct_test
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I appreciate it, however I forgot to include my `dict_SupportVectorMachine `. So I get exactly the `('svm', SVC())` without the `""`. Can it be used to find it ?  str(dict_SupportVectorMachine[...]) didn't work.

Comment: @Test what ?? a second ago your `string` contained a str object, now it is a tuple of : one string + one object, do `print(string[0])` and that's it

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you missed a `)` on the fourth line:

```
import re 
string = "('svm', SVC())"
string2 = "('dct_test', ThisCouldbeLongerAndShorter()))"
subStr = re.findall(r"('(.+?))',",string)
print(subStr)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I appreciate it, however I forgot to include my `dict_SupportVectorMachine `. So I get exactly the `('svm', SVC())` without the `""`. Can it be used to find it ?  str(dict_SupportVectorMachine[...]) didn't work.